# How to optimize a pysapark code to compute the distance by USER?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to compute the average distance made by the `ID` in each `zone`. I am woking in `pyspark` and I am using `geospark`.

My table looks like:

```
+--------------------+--------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  ID|    zone|      date|               point|              point1|
+--------------------+--------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|04607f5b-746e-455...|00295753|2020-03-18|POINT (-80.161590...|POINT (-80.161590...|
|05df916c-6269-485...|01383864|2020-03-17|POINT (-95.581115...|POINT (-95.581115...|
|1973aa17-863f-4de...|01383847|2020-03-17|POINT (-96.864837...|POINT (-96.864837...|
|1bba1026-dcb3-42f...|00465266|2020-03-17|POINT (-95.823860...|POINT (-95.823860...|
|2a16bc8c-a529-42e...|01266994|2020-03-18|POINT (-101.24329...|POINT (-101.24329...|
|352b142f-616e-46b...|01605066|2020-03-17|POINT (-105.73150...|POINT (-105.73150...|
|66952620-0cc2-4ba...|01383943|2020-03-17|POINT (-96.226104...|POINT (-96.226104...|
|7e901a60-9f16-4a9...|01383886|2020-03-19|POINT (-95.496803...|POINT (-95.496803...|
|80fdf1e3-92ca-4b1...|01383813|2020-03-16|POINT (-97.661605...|POINT (-97.661605...|
|81f3eb49-ef3f-48f...|00066975|2020-03-18|POINT (-93.562011...|POINT (-93.562011...|
+--------------------+--------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I would like to compute the sum of the distance made by the users in each zone and total number of distinct users for each zone in each day. I am using `geospark` and I can run simple queries like this

```
queryDistances = """
        SELECT ID, date,
        ST_Distance(point, point1) as distance
        FROM myTable
    """
```

I would like to measure the distance between `point` and `point1` and do the avg distance per`ID` per `date` per zone and the total number of distinct `ID` per day per `zone`.

I would like a table like

```
    zone        date        avg(distance)   tot(users)
  00295753    2020-03-18       5.5              74
  01383864    2020-03-17       7.3              117
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to play with "group by" for sometime. Write query like this

```
select ID, date, AVG(ST_DISTANCE(point,point1)) as avg, count(*) as total
from myTables 
group by ID,Zone,Date
```